Migrating data from on-premises SQL Server to Azure using Azure Data Factory
My look up component in Azure Data Factory is working well but it is not fetching value in for each component - database and copy data to sink location
These are the tables I'm trying to migrate:

Loop-up activity is executing perfectly:

But I getting an error in my for each activity:



I'm trying to copy SalesLT schema tables to Azure Data Lake Gen 2
Error Message
enter image description here

What is the error message? Share the error message from one of the failed copy activities

Can you share screenshot of the copy activity source settings?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - it's important to provide properly-formatted text for things like queries/data/errors/etc. Please edit accordingly.


Incorrect syntax near FROMSalesLt.,

From the error message, it looks like the space is missing between the key word from and @item().Schemaname. This causes the error.
The correct syntax is,
SELECT * FROM [@{item().Schemaname}].[@{item().Tablename}]


When you give the above query in the source tab of copy activity, pipeline will run without any error.
If you want to copy only the SalesLt schema tables, you can also give the query as
SELECT * FROM [SalesLt].[@{item().Tablename}]

